# Error downloading file to local subfolder using WinSCP

Tags: batch-file, download, winscp

I use a batch file to get into WinSCP. The `.bat` reads a script file containing this:

```
cd /download/.stuff
get file.txt D:\Name\Sub Name\Even Lower
```

changes directory fine, finds file fine, but when it comes to placing it in Sub-folder directory on my local computer I get this error

> Can't get attributes of file ' D:\Name\Sub Name\Even'.
>   No such file or directory

I think that the syntax is correct.

Any reason why it's not dropping into that sub folder?

Thanks

Comment: It's probably the spaces, but seems odd it's getting past the first space but not the second. Try putting the whole `"D:\..Lower"` path in quotes? Try using the space-free short-names for those folders (try `dir /X` to find them)?

Comment: Thank you for your response. I tried putting in " " and computer treated it like a file. And when I  take away spaces to call the folder "EVENLOWER", computer saves "EVENLOWER" as a file in D:\Name\Sub Name

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As @Rub mentioned, it's the spaces. You need to enclose the paths with spaces into double-quotes. Also, you need to terminate the path with backslash. Otherwise it's going to download the file to file `Even Lower` in local directory `D:\Name\Sub Name`. But I assume that you want it to download to `D:\Name\Sub Name\Even Lower`, keeping the name `file.txt`.

This is correct syntax:

```
get file.txt "D:\Name\Sub Name\Even Lower\"
```

Some references:
https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scripting#syntax
https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_get

The error message you are getting does not make much sense. When trying the same, I'm getting:

> Can't get attributes of file 'D:\Name\Sub'
>   No such file or directory.

That makes sense as your command means: Download three remote files `file.txt`, `D:\Name\Sub` and `Name\Even` to local file `Lower` in your local current working directory (overwritting one another). So it fails finding remote file `D:\Name\Sub`.

Comment: Martin- You're a WinSCP Superstar! I have seen your work on other sites. I made those changes and it worked.    Děkuji!